# How do I change the default solver in AMPL?

Tags: ampl

AMPL by default uses MINOS. I have to type option solver "./lpsolve"; every time I want to use lpsolve as my solver. Is there a way to change the default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a text file in the directory where AMPL and lpsolve is with the following line:

`option solver './lpsolve';`

Before running ampl, you have to set the `OPTIONS_IN` environment variable and make it point to this newly created text file. I am using bash and I gave the name settings.txt to this text file. Before calling ampl, I issue the following command in the bash shell:

`export OPTIONS_IN=./settings.txt`

There are others ways to do this, and you may use another shell so I don't want to expand on this.

You may find useful the [CPLEX user's guide](http://www.ampl.com/BOOKLETS/amplcplex121userguide.pdf). Even though it's for CPLEX, there are a few sections on ampl that generally apply.

For example all the above I write is in this user's guide, see *Chapter 4 Customizing AMPL*, section *Persistent Option Settings*.

Comment: Thank you!! This worked like a charm. I will also check out the references.